# Combining NASM, BCC and Ld86 in real mode: has bad magic number

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, real-mode, bcc

I wrote a bootloader and compiled it using `NASM` assembler (not `AS86`), everything was working perfectly.

Now, I want to learn how to insert 16-bit `C` code into my application. I read from several SOs that `bcc` is recommended for such situations due to the fact that it supports 8086 processors.

During combining my code with a `C` test code I faced the following error: `ld86: testasm.o has bad magic number`

I reduced my code to the following:

**testasm.asm**:

```
[bits 16]
global foo

foo:
    mov ax, 0x0e41
    int 0x10
    jmp $
```

**testc.c**:

```
extern void foo();

main() {
  foo();
}
```

and the **Makefile**:

```
CFLAGS=-0 -c
LDFLAGS=-T 0x7C00 -0
ASFLAGS=-f aout

all: testc.bin

testc.bin: testasm.o testc.o
    ld86 -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

testc.o: testc.c
    bcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

testasm.o: testasm.asm
    nasm -o $@ $^ $(ASFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o testc.bin
```

and I still have the problem. Any one knows how to combine `NASM`, `bcc` and `ld86` all together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For new comers, I detected the problem. The output format of `NASM` should be `AS86` in order to be compatible with LD86.
So,

```
ASFLAGS=-f aout
```

should be replaced with

```
ASFLAGS=-f as86
```

In addition, the code have another problem:
`foo` in `testasm.asm` should be replaced with `_foo` but don't ask me why!

Comment: Before the introduction of the ELF object format, symbols from the C programming language were prefixed with an underscore to distinguish them from register names and local labels. This is still done one Windows as they never adapted ELF.